# How to specify relationship type in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, syntax, relational-database

Just a quick question regarding MySQL -- I have created the model for my database using MySQL Workbench, and I am currently in the process of writing up the code (I'm sure there's a way to turn the model into the code, but I prefer to write it myself as I am in the process of learning).

I was just wondering, how do you specify whether a relationship is identifying or non-identifying in MySQL syntax?

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    data VARCHAR(45),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE foo2 (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    foo_id UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_foo2_id FOREIGN KEY(foo_id) REFERENCES foo.id,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

How would I make this an identifying relationship?

Also what is the impact of `ON DELETE CASCADE` and `ON UPDATE CASCADE` on such a relationship?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't distinguish the two types of relationships in MySQL.

Comment: `ON DELETE CASCADE` may be as close to an identifying relationship as it gets in SQL.

Comment: That's what I thought, thanks!